# Find location of inline css

Tags: css, server, location, inline

I would like to find the server location of a css (java) file, that is responsible for the logo font / size.

CSS inspector says:  Inline:5

So, that does not give me anything.

Is there any way to find the file loaction?

Thanks

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEuzZ.png)

Comment: Please attach a screenshot also for clarify problem

Comment: Seems likely this is in a `style` tag in the `head`

Comment: thanks. added screenshot. - I was able to find it, by searching the server (grep -rnw) for the name of the file (simply logo). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find it, by searching the server (grep -rnw) for the name of the file (simply logo).
Haven't seen the name of the file before.

[logo a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aneMT.png)

Thanks

Comment: Please post code rather than just images. It's easier to follow and understad.